# how to correct the error and add sum to my sentences?

Tags: tableau-api

[the capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIxXk.png)i create this on the tableau in order to find out how many missing oppo and remaining oppo do i have in the sheet
first i create these 2 parameters and a group which has the completed and imcomplete,and here are my sentences.

```
IF ATTR([Sheet1 (Form_374034_TEMPLATE (1))].[Status of Risk Mitigation (Planned or Complete) (group)])="incompleted"

THEN IF [end date ]<TODAY()

    THEN [Parameters].[missing oppo]

ELSE IF [end date ]>TODAY()

    THEN [Parameters].[remaining oppo]

END
```

i wonder how can i correct it and have the sum of the 2 parameters?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, Your question is not completely clear, to the extent I understand try below:

```
IF ATTR([Sheet1 (Form_374034_TEMPLATE (1))].[Status of Risk Mitigation (Planned or Complete) (group)])="incompleted" and  [end date ]<TODAY()

    THEN [Parameters].[missing oppo]

ELSE IF ATTR([Sheet1 (Form_374034_TEMPLATE (1))].[Status of Risk Mitigation (Planned or Complete) (group)])="incompleted" and [end date ]>TODAY()

    THEN [Parameters].[remaining oppo]

END
```

IF this is not you are looking for then add more detail what exactly you are trying to do.

Edit--------------------------------------------------------------

Count:
This will count of number of records in partition (Including duplicates)

CountD:
This will count distinct records in partition (Excludes Duplicates)

RunningSum:
This will sum the records in partition form first record to last record in partition.

Suppose your data is like below:

```
1
1
2
3
4
5
5
5
```

Count: 8

CountD: 5

RunningSum: 26

Comment: thank you sir i've already solved this,i'm sorry to bother you  but how can i calculated the number of the records for a row?i wonder how many records i have for each row..

Comment: can you update question with image... I am unable to understand `how many records for each row` part

Comment: if your issue is solved the answer your own question and then accept it as answered so that others can use

Comment: emm sorry it's the first time to ask the qusetion here ,i add the photo as the capture,i want to know the number of the records of each row

Comment: if your data is not sensitive then you can upload to any free upload side and post the link here?

Comment: sorry it's confidential..but can you see my capture?i mean i want to know the amount(conut) for blue,orange and red..

Comment: ok... Field that you are using to generate the bars... Take the count of field and then place on `Text` on Marks

Comment: and my bro can you tell me what's the difference between count and countd and running sum?there are 3 rows and i want to write a program so that i can get the 3 directly,which will be more efficient